# How can i send sms to mobile from spring boot application

Tags: spring, text, spring-boot, sms, message

I m building a web application with spring boot.  Its kind of ecommerce site.  I want to send sms text message to users mobile and email message to user email.

Is there any free Apis available for it or any technical solution for it. I need  This feature in india..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any other apis or provider...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are providers for sending SMS like https://www.twilio.com/sms. It has a Rest-API. My experience from a couple of years ago is that sending a considerable amount of SMS costs money, but it is possible that free offers exist today.

Sending emails can be done with an ordinary SMTP-server. You can manage one on your own or use one of a provider. Spring has a high-level API for sending emails: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html.

Comment: If you google for "sms api" for example you will find more providers.

Comment: I tried. And got many..  But all are too costly providers..  So trying to get better api with low budget..

Comment: You could try to search for a domestic provider in India. It could be cheaper.